# Changing MongoDB item value 2 days after created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a NodeJS application that saves form data in MongoDB database collection. I want to run a function that will change some values of the object in MongoDB database collection 2 days after the form data is saved in the database. I am not sure if it is possible to use `setTimeOut()` for 2 days, and even if it is possible, I think there must be a better way to do this because form data is saved upon a request.

My alternative solution is creating setInterval which will run the code once a day to check if there are any database items with dates past but I am still looking for a better solution

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible with `setTimeOut` and `setInterval`. It will be better if you node package like Node Cron or Node Schedule.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the packages.